# Powershell Select-Object - and Hash

Tags: windows, powershell, md5

Can someone tell me whats wrong with this?

```
$MD5Hashes = @{}
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Tony\Pictures\My Pictures\2009\03" -Recurse -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName,Name |  % {
  $MD5Hashes.Add($_.Name, (Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5))
}
```

here's the error:

```
Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Key cannot be null. Parameter name: key" At C:\Users\Tony\Documents\pcloud_sync.ps1:3 char:3
+   $MD5Hashes.Add($_.FullName, (Get-FileHash $_ -Algorithm MD5))
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException
```

I can see that $_ is getting the FullName variable but not sure what the .Name isn't coming through and also nothing seems to get populated in the Get-FileHash logic...

[image]

Kinda new to powershell ...

Comment: `ExpandProperty` only expands one property. Simply remove `-ExpandProperty` or even this whole part:  `Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName,Name`, because it is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing on my comment:

when using `-ExpandProperty`, you are retrieving the **value** of ONE single property, whereas your code tries to get both the FullName and the file's Name.
The rest of the code still uses `$_.Name` as if you have selected **objects** with properties, but because of `-ExpandProperty` that is no longer the case.

The simple fix to that is to remove the `-ExpandProperty` switch or in fact remove the whole part `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName,Name`.

Next:

To add to a Hashtable, you can use its `Add()` method, but this will throw an exception when you try to add a property with a keyname that is already in use.

Since you want to get the filenames recursively, it is more than likely that files from different folders having the same name can occur.

To overcome getting errors from `$MD5Hashes.Add()`, you might use a test first:

```
if (!$MD5Hashes.ContainsKey($_.Name)) {
    # get the hash **value** from the returned object of Get-FileHash
    $md5 = (Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5).Hash
    $MD5Hashes.Add($_.Name, $md5)
}
```

but this will cause filehashes to be skipped when files with the same name occur, meaning only the **first** filename gets stored, all duplicate filenames are lost.

Another way is to directly assign properties to the Hashtable:

```
$MD5Hashes[$_.Name] = (Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5).Hash
```

Although now you won't get exceptions thrown, this will **overwrite** any item already present, meaning the **last** file with a duplicate name will get stored and others are lost.

I would therefore recommend you use the `FullName` of the file as key for the Hashtable to make sure no duplicate keys can occur in the Hashtable and nothing gets lost.